# Is it possible to host static pages on HTTP and Meteor on HTTPS using nginx w/ a redirect?

Tags: nginx, meteor

I have a site I am working on for someone that involves a static informational site with some custom Meteor app.  I would like to have the static site serviced through HTTP with one URL serving as a redirect to HTTPS, where the Meteor app would live.

I have tried several things, with this being the latest attempt for the HTTP-side:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name dev.mysite.com;

    location /app {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/lib/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the static site is created and generated from the Blocs app, and would include a nav link to `/app` that would then redirect back to HTTPS.  The issue I am running into is that, once the browser (tried Chrome and Firefox) has "seen" the HTTPS site, it will not go back to the non-HTTPS site at all.  Any attempt to go to the HTTP site for any URL forces you back to HTTPS.  Also, the redirect on `/app` doesn't seem to work.  I am deploying the Meteor app through mupx, if that helps.

Is this setup even possible, and if so, where is my config wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've managed to resolve this yet, but here are a few starting points as far as the NGINX configuration goes.

When you access `dev.mysite.com/`, it defaults to the / location block and your content gets served. However, when you access `dev.mysite.com/app`, it's returning over https, so you'll need to configure an additional server block to listen on 443 (or you could use `listen ssl`) and set the root or proxy_pass in this block to serve your secure content.

For the case of navigating back to non-HTTPS, it might be that the link you're following specifies to use HTTPS, so I would start there. Also, your URL may contain `.../app/...` in which case it would fall into the `/app` location block and return HTTPS.

One last comment:

If you have a certificate to secure dev.mysite.com, it might be easier to serve all content over HTTPS. If you don't want to do this, then give your  static non-HTTPS site a different subdomain name so that the link can reference this instead and NGINX will be able to deal with it.